# 3rd level page table indirection source code differs from assembly in x86 Linux Kernel

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, reverse-engineering, page-tables

I'm using 4 levels page table (LA57 disabled) and tried to understand the implementation of getting virtual address of the 3rd level page. But encountered difference between source code and it's disassemble.

[Source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/include/linux/pgtable.h#L117):

```
static inline pud_t *pud_offset(p4d_t *p4d, unsigned long address)
{
    return p4d_pgtable(*p4d) + pud_index(address);
}
```

Both `p4d_pgtable` and `pud_index` calls were inlined in the resulting assembly (below). Here are their source code.

[p4d_pgtable](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h#L878):

```
static inline pud_t *p4d_pgtable(p4d_t p4d)
{
    return (pud_t *)__va(p4d_val(p4d) & p4d_pfn_mask(p4d));
}
```

[pud_index](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/include/linux/pgtable.h#L77):

```
static inline unsigned long pud_index(unsigned long address)
{
    return (address >> PUD_SHIFT) & (PTRS_PER_PUD - 1);
}
```

[`PUD_SHIFT` and `PTRS_PER_PUD`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_64_types.h#L80)

```
/*
 * 3rd level page
 */
#define PUD_SHIFT   30
#define PTRS_PER_PUD    512
```

**The problem:** According to the `pud_index` source code I expected it to be compiled with the shift right by `0x1e` (`PUD_SHIFT`) and then anded with `0x1ff` (`PTRS_PER_PUD - 1`). But disassembling `pud_offset` shows different values.

**Disassemble**:

```
(gdb) disas pud_offset
Dump of assembler code for function pud_offset:
   0xffffffff812bfc40 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0xffffffff812bfc41 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp 
   0xffffffff812bfc44 <+4>:     mov    rax,rdi
   0xffffffff812bfc47 <+7>:     nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
   0xffffffff812bfc4a <+10>:    and    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x142936f]        # 0xffffffff826e8fc0 <physical_mask>
   0xffffffff812bfc51 <+17>:    shr    rsi,0x1b #  <---- 0x1b is 27, but 3rd level starts at bit 30
   0xffffffff812bfc55 <+21>:    pop    rbp
   0xffffffff812bfc56 <+22>:    and    rax,0xfffffffffffff000
   0xffffffff812bfc5c <+28>:    and    esi,0xff8 # <---- 4088, but there are 512 entries at the 3rd level
   0xffffffff812bfc62 <+34>:    add    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x14122df]        # 0xffffffff826d1f48 <page_offset_base>
   0xffffffff812bfc69 <+41>:    lea    rax,[rax+rsi*1]
   0xffffffff812bfc6d <+45>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

What we have in the disassemble output is the `address` shifted right by `0x1b`(27) and then anded with `0xff8` (4088 or 511 << 3).

Do you have any idea of why it might happen?

Comment: Each page table entry is 8 bytes, so you get "`offset = index << 3`".  The `shr rsi,0x1b` is like `rsi = (rsi >> 30)  << 3` and the `and esi,0xff8` is like `rsi = rsi & (511 << 3)`. Mostly, it's just doing these things with offsets (and not doing them with indexes)

Comment: @Brendan Perfectly makes sense, but why isn't it reflected in the source code (I mean `<< 3`)? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: I think that's just the way pointers work in C. E.g. if you have `uint64_t * x;` and then `return x + n` the compiler internally multiplies `n` by `sizeof(uint64_t)` (or shifts left by 3 instead of multiplying). In the same way `return p4d_pgtable(*p4d) + pud_index(address);` has an implied multiplication by `sizeof(pud_t)`.

Comment: @Brendan Indeed, thanks much. Didn't pay enough attention to the fact that actually a **pointer to** `pud_t` is being added.  If you'd post I'd accept it as an answer. Damn was scratching my head around it for the whole day.